# ¿Como puedo insertar los datos de un ArrayList<String> a un constructor en java?

Tags: java

llevo muchas horas intentando hacerlo, estoy intentando a través de ficheros, que cuando lea los datos, me los inserte los datos a un constructor de 4 parametros, lo que quiero conseguir es que cuando haya leido esos 4 parametros, se creo otra nueva Revista (es como se llama la clase del construtor), pero siempre y solamente me lo hace el primero. Espero vuestra ayuda. Gracias de antemano. La clase Publicacion es una clase abstracta de Polimorfismo. y la clase Revista extiende de Publicacion. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código de esa clase y el de la clase Revista.

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es los datos que tengo en el ArrayList pasarlo al constructor parametrizado. Pero cuando lo hago, tanto en un for normal como en un foreach, solamente me guarda uno, y tengo más datos en el ArrayList.

Comment: Hola Samuel. No entiendo que necesitas, no se si lo que dices es que en "publicaciones" solo guardas una "revista" y quieres guardar más o que... porque he visto que solo estás guardando una revista pero usas un bucle para mostrar sus datos.
Debes añadir el código necesario para poder ayudarte como texto. Un saludo.

Comment: el codigo que compartes esta incompleto lo mas probable es que el constructor de la clase revista no lo hayas incluido revisa como hacer un [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Si es que entiendo bien tu pregunta, necesitas iterar la lista, para lo cual basta con un simple

```
for(TipoDeDato dato : tuLista) { //cualquier operacion con dato };
```

En tu caso el tipo de dato es String.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero lo he intentado como me lo has dicho y de muchas más formas, pero cuando le paso dato (de tu ejemplo) al constructor me lo inserta pero solamente me inserta los primeros datos, yo quiero que me inserte todos los datos que tengo. Si tengo 2 revistas insertadas con sus datos que esos datos de las Revistas se creen con el constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que crear tantos objetos como palabras haya en tu `arraylist`, es decir, si tienes 24 palabras en el **`array`** y tu constructor admite 4 parámetros son 24/4=6 6 objetos, cada vez que crees un objeto guárdalo en el objeto publicaciones y al final ya lo tendrás